# How to know meaning of parameter in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm new to SuiteScript but gonna built script.

I loaded record which internal id is 'item fulfillment' 
and then using getField function tried to output result of 'shipstatus' field.

I know shipstatus is standard field NetSuite supports.

It outputs 'A'

Is there anyone who could explain what this means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This SuiteAnswer should help:

https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/50165/kw/salesord

Basically, all statuses within SuiteScript return letter codes, and there is a mapping to the status text within NetSuite.